# Graphical problem upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, gtk, 16.10

After upgrading xubuntu 16.04 to xubuntu 16.10 some application have some graphical problems, for exampple evince:

[image: evince in 16.10]

No scroll bar are rendered, buttons have no border, tooltip also have no border or different color, etc.

here is the same pdf file with evince in xubuntu 16.04 (in virtualbox)

[image: evince in 16.04]

some other programs have similar problems:
firefox, eclipse, libreoffice, scite, abiword...

some other programs otherwise has no problems:
thunderbird, inkscape, chrome, gimp...

how can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

```
$ apt-cache policy evince libgtk-3-0  
  evince:  
  Installed: 3.22.0-0ubuntu1  
  Candidate: 3.22.0-0ubuntu1  
  Version table:  
 *** 3.22.0-0ubuntu1 500  
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
libgtk-3-0:  
  Installed: 3.20.9-1ubuntu2  
  Candidate: 3.20.9-1ubuntu2  
  Version table:  
 *** 3.20.9-1ubuntu2 500  
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy evince libgtk-3-0`? It also looks like the theme couldn't be applied correctly. Could please try to set a different GTK theme? That might force things back to normal again. You can set the default theme again afterwards.

Comment: I'll try to change theme

Comment: I changed aspect: the Raleigh seems to have the proble all other no. I have choose Radiance. In the next few day I will test all applications ,   thanks

Comment: At least the packages have the right version and don't hold left-overs from before the system upgrade.